# Noitifications about security updates keeps coming after the update is done

Tags: 7, updating, notifications

I have updated to core version 7.52 and I also ran the database updates accordingly. So why do the notifications keep coming? I have set the update check to be done once a day, and every morning I get an email that states that a security update is available for my version of Drupal. When I click the link the page opens and says that Drupal core is up to date.

Comment: Check if the update notification is regarding Drupal Core or [Contributed modules](https://www.drupal.org/project/project_module)? Also make sure you've run [update.php](https://www.drupal.org/node/1223018) to make sure you've latest database changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the default behavior of the **Update Status** module, which is part of core. Unless you turn it off or reconfigure it, the modules will be checked daily and the site administrator will get email notices.

Comment: Smalution: But it is strange that the notifications keep saying that there are security updates, when there aren't any.